# Python: Break while loop on user command and not suspend the while loop process

Tags: python, loops, user-input, exit

Is there a way to break a while loop based on user command but not suspend the while loop during the check? So something like input() doesn't work because the function suspends the while loop to wait for the user input. A solution that allots time for user to input would not work for us because run-time is a tight requirement.

Comment: You could try to check stdin (select) or use something like asyncio to asyncrounusly wait for input.

Comment: your question is not precise enough, what do you want to check? something based on input? if not, use threading. if it does, use [prompt_toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: You could run `input` and the loop in different threads.